# Limits evaluation of non- algebraic expressions

Tags: calculus, limits

While evaluating the limit $$\lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{1 - \cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x)}{(\sin(2x))^2}$$

Why can't I put the values of $\cos(2x)$ , $\cos(3x) = 0$ in the expression so that I get

$$\lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{(\sin(2x))^2}$$ which can be easily evaluated?

Comment: At $x=0$ we have $\cos 2x=1$ and $\cos 3x=1$. Are you asking whether we can replace the $\cos 2x$ and $\cos 3x$ parts by $1$? If that would work, there would be an equally good case for keeping the $\cos 2x$ and replacing $\cos x$ and $\cos 3x$ by $1$. But that would give a different answer. Suggestion: Series give a straightforward path to the answer.

Comment: Yes , i meant that .

Comment: But what does this mean : "Series give a straightforward path to the answer" ? Can you elaborate it ?

Comment: Informal: For $x$ small, we have $1-\cos( x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x)\approx 1-(1-x^2/2)(1-4x^2/2)(1-9x^2/2)\approx (x^2/2)(14)$. The denominator is about $4x^2$, cancellation gives limit $7/4$.  Or if you prefer use L'Hospital's Rule twice.